# Given S, prove that C is an open cover, but there is no finite subcover of C that covers S.

Tags: real-analysis

Define $$S= \{q \in \mathbb Q : q \in [1, 2] \}$$ and $$C = \{(0, 2^{(1/2)} - \frac{1}{n}) : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{(2^{(1/2)}+\frac{1}{m},3): m \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
I need to prove that $C$ is an open cover of $S$ but there is no finite subcover of $C$ that covers $S$.

I understand this problem intuitively, but I don't know how to state a formal proof.
So, first off, I know that the first part of $C$ covers the open interval from $(0, \sqrt2)$ and the second part of $C$ covers the open interval from $(\sqrt2, 3)$. Therefore, putting these two things together, $C$ is obviously and open cover of $S$. I know that there is no finite subcover since the $\sqrt2$ is not included in either of the covers because we can get infinitely closer to the square root of two but never get there since $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{m}$ can never equal zero. So, technically, the square root of 2 is covered by the two parts of $C$, but there is no finite subcover of $C$ that would actually cover the square root of two.

If someone can help me put this together to make it more coherent and mathematically correct, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You can learn how to do it [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I've edited the math formatting. Let me know if there are any mistakes.

Comment: You don't have to cover $\sqrt 2$, because $\sqrt 2 \notin S$. So your intuition is wrong on this part of the proof.

Comment: @TonyK the square root of 2 is in S because 1 < sqrt(2) < 2...

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt{2}\notin Q$.

Comment: @mmm: The square root of $2$ is not in $S$ because the square root of $2$ is not in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @TonyK okay, I do see that now. So then intuitively, how might I approach understanding the second part of the proof that there is no finite subcover of C that covers S

Comment: Wouldn't it be a similar argument though since you do have rational numbers that get infinitely closer to the square root of two? However, we can not determine a rational number that is indeed the "closest" rational number to the square root of two on either side of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q\in S$.  Then $q\not=\sqrt{2}$ since $\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb{Q}$, so either $q<\sqrt{2}$ or $q>\sqrt{2}$.

If $q<\sqrt{2}$, then by the Archimedean property there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\sqrt{2}-q$, so $q<\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n}$.

If $q>\sqrt{2}$, then similarly there is an $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{m}<q-\sqrt{2}$, so $q>\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{m}$.

This shows that any element of S is in one of the sets in C, so C is an open cover of S.

To show that C has no finite subcover, assume instead that it does have a finite subcover $\{(0,\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n_1}),\cdots,(0,\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n_k}),(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{m_1}),\cdots,(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{m_l})\}$, and then show that there must be an element of S which is not in the union of these intervals.

[Notice that the intervals get larger as n and m get larger.]

Comment: I understand most of the proof, but how did you use the Archimedean property to show that 1/n < sqrt(2) - q?

Comment: You could think of this as $n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-q}$ for some positive integer n, but an equivalent form of the AP says that given $t>0$, there is an $n\in N$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<t$.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not quite seeing it yet. I know that the AP says that for every real number there is a rational number greater than that real number. So did you just formulate some real number that is equal to 1/(sqrt(2)-q)? Or did you conclude this from the fact that q<sqrt(2)?

Comment: I'm using the version of the AP that says that for every real number t, there is a positive integer n such that $n>t$.  In this case, I am using $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-q}$, and then since $\sqrt{2}-q>0$ we can rewrite the inequality as $\frac{1}{n}<\sqrt{2}-q$.